# Attaching Google doc link read from Google spreadsheet to automatic email in script

Tags: google-apps-script

The following code isn't working, giving the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function getFileByID in object Drive.

I'm trying to first test by directly providing ID in the script:

```
var atta = DriveApp.getFileByID('1XD...c'); //ID is Folder and Google Doc ID I                      want to attach

MailApp.sendEmail(emailto, subject, message, {
  cc: emailcc,
  attachments:[atta]
 });
```

Ultimately, I want to read in the link from a Google Spreadsheet:

```
var range = active_actions.getRange(i+1,16) //active_actions is the spreadsheet and i+1,16 is the cell with the link

var link = range.getFormula();
var atta = DriveApp.getFileByID(link); 
MailApp.sendEmail(emailto, subject, message, {
  cc: emailcc,
  attachments:[atta]
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't too difficult. Google Docs/Spreadsheets/etc. CANNOT be placed as an attachment in an E-mail. This is because it isn't actually a 'physical document'. It only exists on the cloud. Instead, put the URL in the email, and it will give the receiver a little box at the bottom with the Doc looking like an attachment.

It's not perfect, but it is good enough. For more details, you can see this issue request or Google's App Script Issue page:

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=585&q=attachment%20types&sort=-stars&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

EDIT (To explain data fetching in SS):

To get data out of a range object, (text, number, etc.), you should use this format.

```
var range = getRange();
var rangeData;
var cellValue;

while (range.hasNext()) {
  rangeData = range.next();
  cellValue = rangeData.getValue();
}
```

If you an accumulator variable, you can get every bit of data in one list/string/etc.

Now that you have your data, you can E-mail it, or do anything else with it.

Comment: Yes, thank you this would work.  Now, I'm trying to read the link with:                               var range = active_actions.getRange(i+1,16) 
     var link = range.getFormula()                                                                                             but nothing is returned.  Also, do I have to place the actual link in the cell or can I use Text

Comment: Now, I'm trying to use

Comment: You can use plain text, as the gmail should automatically interpret any www.sathue.ending as a hyperlink. The other issue I think you are having (it's hard to tell exactly), is that you are trying to get a singular object from a plural.   .getRange() get's a range, a group of cells. Even if it was just one cell, you still have to iterate over the contents of the range in order to get its contents.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I'm being clear enough.  I have cells in a Gspreadsheet that contain text linked to a hyperlink, i.e., "Action Document," which is linked https:...  to a google doc in another folder.  I want to read that link in an apps script and send an automatic e-mail with the link.  Thanks for you patience and help if you can.

Comment: I have edited my answer to hopefully better explain how to get your hyperlinks.

Comment: Thank you.  I can now read the formula:  =HYPERLINK("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XDk2Q3JkIeSrJ5PHxleniRy....","Action Document").   I want to include (underlined) Action Document as a link in the automatic e-mail that is sent and not have to write out the whole https address (which I know can just be read as text (w/o formula) and pasted in, but I'd rather have the shorter link.

Comment: Well, if you are using the GMail API, there is a HTML field. You can tell the gmail to display as HTML if possible (you will still have to write your Email in a normal format, just in case). If you use this approach, you can make a <a>object</a> and use your long hyperlink as the href. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)